# What is the structure and type of harmonics generated by a very differentiated square wave (i.e bipolar spikes)?

Tags: pwm, filter, signal-processing, pulse, fourier

this question is in two parts.
Firstly, can you please tell me what the structure and amplitude distribution is of harmonics generated by a differentiated square wave of 50% duty cycle, where the time constant is very short, producing alternating bipolar spikes of short duration? I know a square wave produces odd order harmonics that decay in amplitude by 1/n, but not sure if the above does - or has even order harmonics as well?
Secondly, what change to the harmonic series and amplitudes occurs for duty cycles tending towards 0% or 100%, from 50%, as if the source was PWM'd by a lower freq signal. Thanks.

Comment: Symmetrical signals don't have even  harmonics

Comment: Just combine (multiply) the harmonic structure of the square wave with the frequency response of a differentiator. Hint: the differentiator's frequency response rises with frequency. Alternatively, just compute the harmonic series of the PWM signal directly, using the Fourier Transform.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can model this as a series of positive and negative Dirac delta functions.  You'll find that this ideal case gives you the (similarly ideal) result mentioned by Dave Tweed in the comments:  the Fourier transform of a square wave multiplied by that of a differentiator.  The drop in amplitude of the square wave harmonics and the rise with frequency of the differentiator cancel out, leaving a series of spikes on the fundamental and odd harmonics, all of equal amplitude.

Comment: OK, if the spikes / odd harmonics are all of equal amplitude at 50% duty cycle, then what changes when the square wave is PWM'd and the negative spike deviates about from its center position between the two positive spikes? Is there a rule like for pwm where if the duty cycle is 20%, or 1/5, every fifth harmonic would be missing?

Comment: No, the even harmonics are missing because the signal is symmetrical in the time domain.  If you change the duty cycle, the even harmonics will start kicking in.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I think I have a clear picture of the process now.